# Modify a string in an XML file while not changing an identical string

Tags: bash, sed

I'm writing a bash script, and I need it to make changes to an XML file, replacing a bunch of different servlet-name items with "disabledController".

I know I can do this using sed, however there are 2 different lines that have the same string, but only one needs to be changed.

For example, I need to change this:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.company.ca.CABackup</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>createCertificateAuthorityBackup</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Into this:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.company.ca.CABackup</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>disabledControler</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>createCertificateAuthorityBackup</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

If I use sed like so:

```
sed "s@<servlet-name>CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup.*@<servlet-name>disabledController</servlet-name>@"
```

It replaces both servlet-name items instead of just the 2nd one. Is there a way to do what I want to do here?

Comment: I think xmlstarlet has an option to do that

Answer (score 1):

To replace just the second occurrence, use nesting and pattern ranges beginning from the start of the file:

```
sed -i '0,/CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup/! { 0,//s//disabledController/ }' file
```

Or in full:

```
sed -i '0,/CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup/! { 0,/CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup/s/CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup/disabledController/ }' file
```

Explanation of the longhand command:

```
0,/CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup/      # is a pattern range from the start of
                                          # the file to the first occurrence of:
                                          # 'CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup'

! { ... }                                 # if not in the above pattern range, do
                                          # every between the braces.

0,/CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup/      # match between the beginning of the
                                          # file again and the next occurrence
                                          # of 'CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup'

s/ ... / ... /                            # perform the necessary substitution
```

---

If you'd like to replace the third occurrence, just add another layer of nesting:

```
sed '0,/CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup/! { 0,//! { 0,// s//disabledController/ } }' file
```

*EDIT:*

To make changes between the 'servlet-mapping' tags, all you need is a single pattern range:

```
sed '/<servlet-mapping>/,/<\/servlet-mapping>/s/CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup/disabledController/' file
```

You may like to read more about pattern ranges [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29). HTH.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what's actually happening here?

Also, sometimes the one that needs to be changed isn't the 2nd one. It could be the first or the 3rd in rare cases.

Comment: @jkitzmiller: You did say you wanted to replace 'just the 2nd' occurrence. How are you defining which occurrence to change? Would saying that you'd like to replace the _last_ occurrence be accurate?

Comment: Fair enough, I did say that. I think the most accurate way of stating it is that I want to change the occurrence inside the servlet-mapping tag.

Comment: @jkitzmiller: Please see the edit I've made above. It will perform  the substitution between opening and closing 'servlet-mapping' tags only. HTH.

Comment: @jkitzmiller: Don't forget to accept the answer. You can do this by clicking on the tick to the left of it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML tool to modify XML. This makes the solution much more robust and standards compliant than treating it as text. Replacement won't fail if the file is reformatted according to XML rules, and won't break if other XML standard tools operate on the same file.

You can use `xmlstarlet` to replace the `servlet-mapping` whose `servlet-name` value is `CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup` like this:

```
xmlstarlet edit -L \
  -u '/web-app/servlet-mapping/servlet-name[normalize-space(text())="CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup"]' \
  -v "disabledController"  web.xml
```

given a `web.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.ca.CABackup</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CreateCertificateAuthorityBackup</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>createCertificateAuthorityBackup</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```